# NSImage from NSPasteBoard to base64 for HTTP POST not working as expected

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm playing around with trying to create a little menu item app to learn Cocoa/OS X programming.

Basically it's something that sits in your dock, you drag an image file to it, and it will upload the file to imgur and tell you the URL it was uploaded to.

It "works" in that imgur's API doesn't throw any errors back at me, but the images don't render properly either.

Applicable code:

*ScreenshotController.m*

```
- (void)uploadImage:(NSImage *)image
{
    NSData *imageData = [image TIFFRepresentation];
    NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData];
    imageData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];


    NSString *base64 = [imageData encodeBase64WithNewlines: NO];

    NSString *jsonRequest = @"key=92428d1a5839df89cb8e87e8a31cd935&image=";

    jsonRequest = [jsonRequest stringByAppendingString:[base64 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"Request: %@", jsonRequest);

    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [jsonRequest UTF8String] length: [jsonRequest length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://api.imgur.com/2/upload"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

    NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil ];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Returned Json: %@", returnString);
}
```

*StatusItemView.m*

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *dragTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSURLPboardType, NSFileContentsPboardType, NSFilenamesPboardType, nil];
        [self registerForDraggedTypes:dragTypes];
    }

    return self;
}
//perform the drag and log the files that are dropped
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender 
{
    NSPasteboard *pb = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    if([[pb pasteboardItems] count] != 1){
        return NO;
    }

    if([NSBitmapImageRep canInitWithPasteboard:pb]){
        NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithPasteboard:pb];
        [[[ScreenshotController alloc] autorelease] uploadImage:image];

        return YES;
    }   

    return NO;
}
```

Here is an example image it uploaded to imgur, so you can see what I mean: http://imgur.com/6pLgG (the source file was a perfectly normal PNG).

Complete source code is here if you need to see anything else: https://github.com/zbuc/imgur

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a way to upload to the anon api, I hope this helps out.

```
- (void)uploadImageToImgur{
NSData   *_imageData  = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,90);
NSString *urlString = @"http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// file
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"image\"; filename=\".tiff\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:_imageData]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// text parameter
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//Set API key
[body appendData:[@"API_STRING_HERE" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// close form
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// set request body
[request setHTTPBody:body];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    NSArray *decodedResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    NSString *imgurUrlString = [[[decodedResponse valueForKey:@"upload"] valueForKey:@"links"] valueForKey:@"imgur_page"];        

    [self uploadToImgurCompleteWithUrlString:imgurUrlString];

}];
```

}